# Translate command-line cURL to PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have a working cURL request I want to translate to PHP code:

```
curl \
    -X POST \
    -u live_abcdefg: \
    -d '{
        "recipient": {
            "address": "test1@test.com"
        }
    }' \
    https://api.sendwithus.com/api/v1/drip_campaigns/abcdefgh/activate
```

Here is the PHP code I'm trying:

```
<?php

$theurl = "https://api.sendwithus.com/api/v1/drip_campaigns/abcdefgh/activate";

$ch = curl_init($theurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST'); // -X
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{ "recipient": { "address": "test2@test.com" } }'); // -d
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'live_abcdefg:'); // -u
$response = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($response); // prints bool(true)

?>
```

EDIT: Sendwithus (the app that I'm sending requests to) shows that the second request didn't come through (second recipient test2@test.com wasn't saved).
What am I doing wrong?
What can I change in the PHP code to start debugging this issue?

Comment: we don't know what you are doing wrong, since you do not tell us what the issue here is...

Comment: What makes you think you're doing something wrong? Is there an error? Is a particular part not working? What is the intended result of the PHP code? What happens when you run it?

Comment: @kb.  Sorry I wasn't clear. I edited the question, hopefully it makes sense now.

Comment: Where is CURLOPT_URL and CURLOPT_POST in it?

Comment: $ch = curl_init();
 and then 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");

Comment: @MangeshSatheIND thanks.
I added $ch = curl_init(); and then curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com/");
It didn't work. Maybe I need to set CURLOPT_POST too?

Comment: Yes, also go through http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php